# Register a custom HTML element in TypeScript - Ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I created a component (directive) in TypeScript for **Ionic 2**, the component as a selector `<search-result>` and as we work with semantic HTML and we also style following HTML semantics, I would like to register this HTML element.

I'm using TypeScript and I've already tried `document.registerElement` but it says that document does not exist on type 'Document'.

That is my code:

```
import {Component, Input} from "@angular/core";
import {NavController, NavParams} from "ionic-angular";
import {IONIC_DIRECTIVES} from "ionic-angular";

@Component({
    selector: "search-result",
    directives: [IONIC_DIRECTIVES],
    templateUrl: "build/pages/components/search-result/search.result.html"
})
export class SearchResultComponent {
    constructor() {
        document.registerElement("search-result");
    }
}
```

Here is the error message in code:

[image]

How do I register an element? Am I missing a `import`?

Comment: Why exactly do you need to register that tag?

Comment: that was the point I was trying to access the DOM-Element with CSS but I was trying this `[search-result] {}` and should be only `search-result {}`

Answer (score 0):

This is a strange error message. You should provide the whole exception text.

Try to change `document.registerElement("search-result");` to `window.document.registerElement("search-result");`

**EDIT:**

You are trying to use a feature that is still draft and not yet officially part of the DOM. Therefore they won't likely be included in TypeScript until they are finalised.

You can prevent the compiler error message by writing `(<any>document).registerElement("search-result");`

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this is not needed. Once a directive/component is registered the tag is automatically registered.